# What is meant by a "two-lane" road?

Tags: word-usage

When people say that a road has "two lanes"?

1. Two lanes total, one travelling in one direction, and one travelling in the opposite direction?

[image: Two lanes total, one travelling in one direction, and one travelling in the opposite direction]

2. Two lanes travelling in one direction, and two more lanes travelling in the opposite direction?

[image]

Comment: In the US a "two-lane road" is one (single-vehicle-width) lane in each direction.  (A "one-lane-road" is either a single one-way lane, or a single lane where vehicles must somehow take turns going opposite directions.)

Comment: @HotLicks, a "one-lane road" can also refer to the "lane-and-a-half" dirt roads found in extremely rural area, where two vehicles can pass with care, but not at normal driving speed.

Comment: @Mark - Yes.  Usually such a road includes true one-lane segments, but at intervals it's wide enough to allow two (relatively narrow) vehicles to pass each other.  This kind of falls into the "somehow take turns" mechanism I mentioned.

Comment: Around here, "two lane" refers to the former and the latter would be a "twin lane", though I'm not sure if this is a Canadianism or not.  We also have the verb "twinning" for the process of turning the former into the latter.

Answer (score 11):

[Two-lane expressway](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-lane_expressway) (same concept as road) :

> - A two-lane expressway or two-lane freeway is an expressway or freeway with only one lane in each direction, and usually no median barrier.

***Two-lane expressway:***
[image]

***Two-lane road:***

[image]

Wikipedia

Your second picture represents a:

***[multilane road/highway](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/multilane):***

> - (of roads and highways) having two or more lanes for traffic

[image]

Comment: Josh, I wouldn't call your top picture a typical "2-lane road" - it's an expressway.  An expressway has entrance and exit ramps.  The lanes are *usually* divided by a median barrier or grass barrier and an expressway has a  generally higher speed limit.  A 2-lane road is a road with one lane in each direction, divided by a double yellow line, intersected with other streets controlled either by 2-or 4-way stop signs and/or traffic lights.

Comment: @KristinaLopez - I  added a picture and descriptions, hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Yeah, that completes it @Josh61! :-)

Comment: @KristinaLopez I am still not absolutely clear about what you call a 'lane'. Does Josh's last picture have two 'lanes', or six 'lanes'? (In our parlance it is a 'three-lane motorway'.) But what do you call a 'carriageway'? I know it's not 'carriageway', as the term always evokes amusement in Americans. If I wanted to say, for example, 'the northbound carriageway was completely jammed for ten miles due to an accident', how would that translate into American?

Comment: @WS2 the bottom picture is called a “6 lane ***highway***” in the US.  “I-17 northbound is backed up for 10 miles due to an accident.”. You can refer to the whole thing as a freeway but you must revert to *highway* when you add the lane width descriptor.

Comment: @Jim But the 'northbound' what? What do you actually call one half of the road where all traffic is moving in the same direction? Or let's say you want to say *the accident spilled over into the other carriageway*. How would you say that?

Comment: I guess we just call it a side when forced to. But we generally just use the route name and then <direction>bound  E.g., the accident on US60 westbound is also affecting eastbound traffic.   Or  a car travelling west on US 60 crossed the median into the eastbound lanes resulting in a head-on collision with a 18-wheeler.

Comment: @WS2--it spilled over into the northbound lanes.

Comment: @Jim In Califiornia, at least, freeway and highway are not the same thing. For one thing, a freeway has controlled access, whereas a highway does not. I can't tell you all the differences, but I know that I can ride my bike on a highway, but not a freeway.

Comment: @Jim The language diverges considerably here. The 'median' is entirely new to me. We call it the 'central reservation'. And I'm sure I would find it difficult managing without a word for 'carriageway'.

Comment: @WS2 note that you only have a median if there's a physical separation of some kind between the opposing direction of travel.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_strip

Comment: @WS2, lane is the single-vehicle path. A two-lane road allows two vehicles, each going in the opposite direction.  A multi-lane expressway has each side identified as "Eastbound I-55" or "Northbound I-294", for example, standing in for the UK's "carriageway".

Answer (score 7):

According to the World Road Association-PIARC, an international standards body, a *[two-lane road](http://www.piarc.org/en/Terminology-Dictionaries-Road-Transport-Roads/term-sheet/67962-en-two-lane+road.htm?ls=en)* is simply a

> Road designed to permit two lanes of traffic to be accommodated side by side.

A search on the term shows that this usage is used by governments and construction companies in the United States, Canada, New Zealand, and Scotland. We may presume that at least in industry circles, the understanding of a two-lane road would be something like what the *[Manual on Uniform Traffic Control Devices](http://www.mutcd.fhwa.dot.gov/)*, which sets US national standards for road signs and markings, [offers in this diagram](http://mutcd.fhwa.dot.gov/services/publications/fhwaop02090/twtmarkings_longdesc.htm):

[image: US MUTCD diagram of two-lane roadways]

Roads with more than two lanes, regardless of direction of traffic, are referred to generically as *multi-lane* roadways.

However, *lanes* should not be confused with *carriageways* or with directions of travel. Consider, for instance, this Wikimedia image of highway 401 in Ontario:

[image: Traffic on the 401]

There are sixteen to seventeen lanes of traffic, but these are divided up into six carriageways, three in each direction. So the confusion that a *four-lane road* refers to a road with four lanes in one direction may arise because it is hard to imagine such a large road on a single carriageway; almost certainly it would be at least a dual carriageway, with four lanes of traffic in each direction, but properly an *eight-lane* roadway.

Comment: To truly appreciate a 2-lane road, it helps to know a road that isn't. Here's one... (best bit from 3:00 to 5:50). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EHKCymOzDcY  It actually works remarkably well, outside tourist season. Everybody else uses the passing places to allow overtaking, as well as passing in opposite directions.

Answer (score 1):

A two lane road means one lane in each direction.  Otherwise, there would be no need for special instructions, like [this one](http://www.driversedguru.com/drivers-ed-training-exercises/stage-4/stage-4-passing-on-two-lane-roads/), teaching drivers how to safely pass on a two lane road.

Answer (score 0):

A ***two-lane road*** is the simplest road possible - no central dividing of the traffic, other than for a dotted line - just one 'lane' in each direction. But in Britain it is usually called a ***single-carriageway road***.

In Britain this is a [*single-carriageway* road](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7b/A511road004.JPG):

It is also what I would call a two-lane road.

This is a [*two-lane dual carriageway*](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d8/A63%28T%29_1.jpg/250px-A63%28T%29_1.jpg)

This is a [*four-lane* motorway](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/20/M40burtley.jpg)

with a northbound and a southbound carriageway.

The word ***carriageway*** (sometimes written as two separate words) long predates the internal combustion engine. It is defined as 'that part of a road which is open to vehicular traffic', in the early days this would have been horse-drawn. (OED).

Comment: Good except for “lane == carriageway” in US.  A lane is a strip of “carriageway” which can only be occupied by a single vehicle at a time at any point along the roadway.  A vehicle can ‘change lanes” by steering to cross the dotted white line into an adjacent lane. With a typical single-lane exit ramp a vehicle must be in the right lane to exit the freeway.

Comment: I'm just going to come right out and say it: American English does not have a word for "carriageway" (though the word "roadway" comes close.) The word "lane" means the same thing on both sides of the pond.

Comment: Of course we talk about the northbound/southbound, or eastbound/westbound carriageway. But in the case of the M25 (the motorway which circles London) it is the *clockwise/anti-clockwise* carriageway.

Comment: @gatkin Yes, I can see now that 'lane' means the same thing. But what do you say on those dreadful occasions (and they must happen anywhere) where some maniac finds his way on to the wrong carriageway? You must know the joke about the woman who phones her husband to urge him to be careful as police report that someone is driving up the wrong carriageway, and he responds with - 'there are scores of vehicles going the wrong way on my carriageway'.

Comment: Sorry, this is incorrect.  We don't have an equivalent of carriageway in the states.

Comment: @WS2 as mentioned above we give the direction and road name.  As you note you can only have two carriageways which go in opposite directions, so "there's an accident on the I95 northbound" (or just north) implies traffic is ok in the southbound direction.  If its an issue with a particular lane, "there's a van broken down in the center northbound lane of I95" which implies a six lane (3 north, 3 south) as you need 3 in one direction to have a center lane.

Comment: Americans would call the "northbound carriageway" the "northbound lane***s***". Note the plural.

Comment: No one in the US pays attention to British traffic terminology.  They drive on the wrong side of the road.  Or is that carriageway?

Comment: @deadrat It does appear that traffic terminology etc. is a particularly important are of divergence between what you speak and what we speak, as may be evident when you look at the British [Highway Code](http://www.highwaycodeuk.co.uk/uploads/3/2/9/2/3292309/the-official-highway-code-with-annexes-uk-en-12-04.pdf) . You will be surprised to find that we have *flyovers* (overpass) and *roundabouts*.

Comment: @WS2 "A two-lane road is the simplest road possible" - not true of course. Consider a single-lane one-way road.

Comment: WS2 - You need to be careful. Speaking form a technical, engineering perspective: "Single carriageway" says nothing about how much lanes there are. You can have single carriageways with 4 lanes, or with only one lane (as @RobinElvin points out). Single carriageway just means there is no physical division (paint doesn't count) between directions.

Comment: @RobinElvin Well of course. But then the simplest is perhaps an unmade cart track across a farm or open country.

Comment: @AndyT  Yes. Good point. But there are few *single- carriageways* with more than one lane in each direction left in the UK. For safety reasons they tend to put in central barriers. Fifty years ago there used to be three-lane roads; one lane each way and the central one for overtaking in either direction. The middle lane got nicknamed the 'suicide lane' by some people. In Ireland, a country of low population density, they have some excellent roads, with two lanes in each direction, but the left-hand one is for slow agricultural vehicles. They are an excellent arrangement, in my view.

Comment: @WS2 - I agree that the "central lane for overtaking in either direction" has fallen out of favour, but plenty of them have been converted to "one lane in one direction and two in the other" while retaining the status of single carriageway.